# Proper way to separate nowjs code from app.(coffee/js)

Tags: node.js, coding-style, code-cleanup, nowjs-sockets

Is there a proper way to separate out my nowjs code from the app file?

```
everyone = require("now").initialize app, { socketio: { transports: ['xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling'] } }

everyone.now.distribute_event = (event, day) ->
  everyone.now.receive_event @now.name, event, day
```

I'm guessing you would define the functions elsewhere like routes? Something like below?

```
nowtes = require('./nowtes')

everyone = require("now").initialize app, { socketio: { transports: ['xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling'] } }

everyone.now.distribute_event = nowtes.distribute_event
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get something working by doing this:

```
global.now = require("now")
global.everyone = now.initialize app,
  socketio:
    transports: [ 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling' ]

nowtes = require "./nowtes"

everyone.now.distribute_event = nowtes.distribute_event
```

In nowtes/index.coffee

```
exports.distribute_event = (activity, day) ->
  everyone.now.receive_event @now.name, activity, day
```

Looks much cleaner to me.